# How To Make An iBindingList Powershell

Tags: winforms, sorting, powershell, data-binding, datagridview

I am working on an UI in Powershell and have ran into a roadblock. I queried a computers win32_service and put the output into a Datagridview by using an ArrayList and I would like to be able to sort the output. I learned after the fact that I cannot call Datagridview.Sort() when I use a list as a datasource. The error tells me that I need an iBindingList in order to sort. This is where I'm at

```
$services = get-wmiobject win32_service
$datagrid = new-object system.windows.forms.datagridview
$databinding = new-object system.componentmodel.ibindinglist
$databinding.add($services)
$datagrid.datasource = $databinding
```

this will error with: "new-object: constructor not found. cannot find an appropriate constructor for type system.componentmodel.ibindinglist"

I can't really find any information about iBindingList for powershell on the internet. Everything I've seen so far has been about c# or c++ and it seems pretty easy in those to declare an iBindingList. Maybe there is an even better way than an iBindingList, any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: test `Get-Service | Out-GridView`

Answer (score 1):

`IBindingList` is an interface, not a class, and as such doesn't have a constructor.

You'll have to create an object of a type *implementing* the `IBindingList` interface, such as the generic [`BindingList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

```
$DataBindingList = New-Object System.ComponentModel.BindingList[Object] 
$DataBindingList.Add($services)
$Datagrid.DataSource = $DataBindingList
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This worked to create the bindinglist but the result is not what i expected. When I display the datagridview in a form it shows the properties of the bindinglist object but not the actually information inside of the object. I tried to do:
    $datagrid.datasource = $databindinglist[0]

This gives me an empty datagridview but if i write-host $databindinglist[0] i see the information i want.